# Question about port forwarding on router

Tags: router, port-forwarding

How to forward from from port 222 to 22 inside local network to ip 192.168.1.103 for example?

Have router TPL-Link TL-WR740N_V1

Setting allow to forward only outside port, but not for ip inside local network.

Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Manual and simulator](http://www.tp-link.com/simulator/TL-WR740N_v1&v2/index.htm) available on line addresses the Virtual servers. (Click Virtual-server on the left). But doesn't allow port forwarding seemingly, (but try the interface anyway or an update of the firmware - it is maybe available now, sometimes web sites are not updated real time).

What you could do is to set the *service port* to 222, with the IP 192.168.1.103, then configure SSH to listen on port 222 on your server (if Ubuntu, Linux, go to /etc/ssh and edit `sshd_config` Port section).

Comment: Yea thanks man, i was thinking the same way. But didn't knew how to do it. ;) Basically i need only need to configure 8080 for http and 222 for ssh. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think your router can do this kind of port forward. Your best bet is probably purchasing a different router.