# Port forwarding, port range?

Tags: port-forwarding

I want to map a local port on my computer, say `3000`, to my public ip address, but my router (SMC 8013WG) has this admin panel which is not very helpful, and it gives me a lot of empty fields.

I have a public *and* private port range, as well as a protocol and IP address, but I don't know what to put?

Why would I **have** to put a range for the ports, cannot I not just have a single port?

Comment: Why are people voting to close this? It's directly related to networking.

Comment: It sounds like personal, not work networking.

Comment: No, I want to expose a rails application that I'm building to other users while it's in development, I'm a consultant, yes, my server is at my home, so? If it's off-topic, why doesn't this one have any votes to close: http://serverfault.com/questions/215392/question-about-port-forwarding-on-router?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

For mapping a single port, you can usually just enter the same number for both parts of the range.

So your information is going to looking something like, "forward public TCP ports 3000 to 3000 to 192.168.1.10 ports 3000 to 3000" where "TCP" is the protocl and "192.168.1.10" is the address of your internal machine.